# React state randomly changes to the value 1

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-functional-component

I am trying to program a file explorer sort of thing. In it I have a state "expandedGroups" that keeps the groups that are already expanded and is used to check, on click, whether it should expand or contract its content. However the value of that state, in a certain point of the program changes to the number 1. Here is the code of the component.

```
useEffect
(
    () =>
    {
        try
        {
            const runEffect = async () =>
            {
                const response = await api.get
                (
                    "/grouplevelindex",
                    {
                        params:
                        {
                            level: 0
                        }
                    }
                );
                setGroups (response.data);
            }
            runEffect();
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            throw new Error (error);
        }
    },
    []
);

useEffect
(
    () =>
    {
        console.log ("At the useEffect");
        console.log (expandedGroups);
    },
    [expandedGroups]
);

function handleGroupClick (index, group)
{
    console.log ("Before the check");
    console.log (expandedGroups);
    if (expandedGroups !== 1 && expandedGroups.includes (group))
    {
        handleContract (index, group);
    }
    else
    {
        handleExpand (index, group);
    }
}

async function handleExpand (index, group)
{
    if (expandedGroups !== 1)
    {
        setExpandedGroups (expandedGroups.push (group));
    }
    console.log ("After the set");
    console.log (expandedGroups);
    for (var k = 0; k < group.content.length; k++)
    {
        const _id = group.content [k];
        const response = await api.get
        (
            "/groupidindex",
            {
                params:
                {
                    _id
                }
            }
        );
        setGroups (groups.splice (index+1+k, 0, response.data));
        setGroups (groups);
        console.log ("After the API request");
        console.log (expandedGroups);
    }
}

async function handleContract (index, group)
{
    //...
}

return (
    <div className = "groupExplorerArea">
        {
            groups.map
            (
                (group, index) =>
                {
                    return (
                        <div key = {index} className = "group">
                            <button
                            className = "buttonGroup"
                            onClick = {() => handleGroupClick (index, group)}
                            key = {index}>
                                {group.name}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    </div>
)
```

First off, I put some if checks round so that the code doesn't break before I have the chance to analyse what happened. I made some tests with console.logs and with an effect that activates only when that state changes. It has show me that it changes to 1 at the useEffect but becomes normal again soon after. Here is are the console.logs after the first click.

Before the check [], After the set [{…}], At the useEffect 1, After the API request [{…}], After the API request [{…}].

And here are the console.logs after a second click.

Before the check 1, After the set 1, After the API request 1, After the API request 1.

Comment: `setExpandedGroups(expandedGroups.push(group));` the return value of `push` is the new length of the array

Comment: @Nicholas Tower Thank you very much. I didn't know that. How should I set the state's value then?

Comment: Actually, I suppose I could do it myself.

Comment: I once heard a voice from the sky telling me 'If you have the answer you need, find a way to give your thanks to the provider.'. Maybe turning @NicholasTower 's answer into comment and valid answer is the righteous path ! ;)

Comment: @QuentinGrisel If you mean turning his comment into the answer for question, how do I do that? If not, sorry. Sometimes I am slow to understand stuff.

Comment: I meant that haha :p I don't know how to do it, I never ask anything haha sorry (and yeah, from comment to answer, not answer to comment :x)